# Should continue with loop after Logging in Error File in Spring Integration

Tags: spring, spring-integration

This is my Scenario.I have to process a File and from the read Objects have to do some business logic. These are like lines from the file. In my Error Handler I write the first line which fails but I have to continue with the next line and should write the next failed line in to the same File. But once the first exception is thrown and the failed line is written it exits the loop. Is there any way to handle this??

Answer (score 0):

When asking questions like this, you need to show your configuration so we can provide more concrete solutions.

There are several ways to solve the problem - including

1. add a mid-flow gateway to the flow and handle the error on it's error channel.
2. add an `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` to the component that throws the exception and handle the exception there. See [Adding Behavior to Endpoints](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#message-handler-advice-chain).